# R: what does it mean by a file being "free formatted" or "fixed formatted"?

Tags: r

[A website](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/inputdata_R.htm) says that

> Importing **free formatted (delimited) data files** using the read.table
>   function
>
> The read.table function is very useful when reading in **ASCII files that contain rectangular data**.

Before reading it, I thought that a free formatted file could contain any thing however organized or unorganized, and ASCII files that contained rectangular data were fixed formatted.
So I wonder what a file being "free formatted" or "fixed formatted" mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I fould some definitions from this [guide](http://documentation.microfocus.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.microfocus.eclipse.infocenter.enterprisedeveloper.vs/HHWZRHSQWZ6V.html):

> **Delimited**, free-format ASCII Files
> allow variable field lengths-- each
> field is separated by a field delimiter.
>
> **Columnar**, fixed-format ASCII
> Files have fixed field lengths-- data is arranged in columns. Every
> record fits into a standard form, so field delimiters are not
> required.

So in my opinion each free-formatted file is a delimited file and fixed-formatted is a fixed width file.